# Repeating background image in native iPhone app

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, native, repeat

Short of putting a UIWebView as the back-most layer in my nib file, how can I add a repeating background image to an iPhone app (like the corduroy look in the background of a grouped UITableView)?

Do I need to create an image that's the size of the iPhone's screen and manually repeat it using copy and paste?

Answer (score 161, accepted):

Apparently a UIColor is not necessarily a single color, but can be a pattern as well. Confusingly, this is not supported in Interface Builder.

Instead you set the backgroundColor of the view (say, in -viewDidLoad) with the convenience method +colorWithPatternImage: and pass it a UI Image. For Instance:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"gingham.png"]]; 
}
```

Of course, don't forget to add the image file to your application bundle.

There are also some built-in background pattern "colors":

- groupTableViewBackgroundColor
- viewFlipsideBackgroundColor

Because the are used globally across all iPhone apps, you incur the double-edged sword of an OS update updating the look and feel of your application (giving it a fresh new look that may or may not work right).

For instance:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor groupTableViewBackgroundColor]; 
}
```

Comment: Would you please provide a code snippet on how to use groupTableViewBackgroundColor? Thanks!

Comment: Good to mention that colorWithPatternImage does not seem to support PNG24

Comment: Is there anything more memory efficient than this?

Comment: This was easier to implement than I thought it was going to be. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 2):

You should have a look at the QuartzDemo iPhone example code from Apple, specifically QuartzImageDrawing.m. Should use the following method call.

```
CGContextDrawTiledImage
```

Answer (score 2):

You can even have an animated tiled background images that move. :D

[Apps Amuck](http://www.appsamuck.com/) has a simple tutorial that show you how to do this on their site.

[31 Days of iPhone Apps - Day 16: World Tour](http://appsamuck.com/blog/index.php/2008/10/16/31-days-of-iphone-apps-day-16-world-tour/)

Answer (score 1):

You should use colorWithPatternImage