# How can I make a variable background image in my iOS APP

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiimage

I am making an iPhone app, and I want know how make a variable background image a background that the user can choose one of the options ?

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/224503/repeating-background-image-in-native-iphone-app

Answer (score 8):

I don't know what you want in the foreground, but anything based on the UIView class has a `backgroundColor` property that you can set to an image like this:

```
yourView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"YourImage.png"]];
```

Answer (score 0):

It didn't work for me, what it worked was:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"]];
```

I think is the same, but don't know why the other answer didn't work for me.

Hope it helps.