# background images for android and IOS

Tags: android, ios, iphone, image, background

I have 5 images background, i want bg can randomly to shown, included horizontal and Vertical，i need to prepare 4 set (iphone&pad) X 5 images = 20 images for each OS? Android also need to prepare 4 X 5 set. is it right? Except this way, still have another method?
If follow above method, the file size at least have 40MB.

Comment: On iOS you can save some space by omitting the normal resolution and only including the 2x artwork, so you only need 10 images.  Technically you can omit the 2x and just use the 1x, but at reduced image quality.

Answer (score 0):

Is this background image texture based or of a repeating pattern? In that case, you can use a Nine-Patch image for the Android app, thus resulting in smaller size (still need to provide for different dpis).

For iOS, probably something on the same lines as given here:

[Repeating background image in native iPhone app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/224503/repeating-background-image-in-native-iphone-app)

Few more links that can be of help for this scenario:

- http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2011/08/22/using-pattern-images-to-set-background-views.html
- http://kylewbanks.com/blog/Android-iOS-Repeating-Background-Image